# How to Identify differences and factors that contribute to difference between two groups

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

Hi all – I’m tasked with a problem to understand productivity rates of two groups. Let’s call them A and B. The ask is to understand if the productivity rates between the two groups is significant and if so, what factors contribute to those differences.

I’m thinking of a conducting a regression analysis predicting productivity rate(Y) and the group(A/B) as categorical variable with other explanatory variables.

Are there any pitfalls here? Also, is there a better approach to do this?

Business context: Hypothesis is that group A is doing better than B. The ask is to understand why and if we can get B up to speed with A